# Server 2012 action centre setting greyed out

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

First time asker long time reader :) im having trouble at the moment on one of my clients servers we need to change the setting on the action centre and most of the checkboxes are greyed out and we are unable to change them any help would be appreciated :)

Kevin

Comment: This is sometimes caused by the items being overridden by group policy.  I'm not certain enough to post this as an answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the action center settings aren't supposed to be changed on a Windows Server system as they are only messages, and don't impact performance in any way.

They can however be modified by changing the values of the registry key.

**This is done at your own risk, and you should always have a backup of registry keys before changing them**

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Action Center\Checks`